# retrieve input type file value using get method

Tags: php

i m trying to update images using GET method

user_form.php

```
<form action='upload.php' method='get'>  
  <input type='file' name='user_img' />
  <input type='text' name='username' />
  <input type='submit' name='update' value='update'>
</form>
```

upload.php

```
if(isset($_GET['update']))
{
  echo 'username: '.$_GET['username'];
  echo 'file name: '.$_FILES['user_img']['tmp_name'];
}
```

i m getting correct value for username, however, blank value for filename.

can anyone please let me know if we can use $_FILES variable for GET method? if yes then please point out where m i going wrong in the above sample code. thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot upload files using a GET HTTP request. Files are sent in the HTTP body, which requires a POST or PUT request.

Comment: +1 - really? I don't know that?

Answer (score 3):

You need to do:

```
<form action="someaction.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your form tag:

```
enctype = multipart/form-data
```

Comment: Refer this and you will learn: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

Comment: +1 - like `<form action="upload.php" method="get" enctype = "multipart/form-data" >`

Answer (score 1):

You should send your form by post method and specify that this form will have a file

```
<form action='' method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
  <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="30000" /> 
  <input type='file' name='user_img' />
  <input type='text' name='username' />
  <input type='submit' name='update' value='update'>
</form>
```

It is also preferable for reasons of security and performance to indicate the maximum size of files to be sent.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `enctype = multipart/form-data` in a form if you want to upload /use files.